# Comparing individual matrix elements in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, comparison

I need to compare a value in a multidimentional array and according to this comparison, I need to assign a value of another matrix in the same index to a new matrix of the same size in the same index. Can you give me an idea on how to do this?

Here's the code below using the for loop, but I need to do this without using a for loop.

```
for i = 1:sizeOfMatrix(1, 1)
   for j = 1:sizeOfMatrix(1, 2)
      if grayImage(i, j) > t
          result(i, j) = 0;
      else
          result(i, j) = grayImage(i, j);
      end
   end
end
```

where t is the value that I need to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
result = zeros(size(grayImage));
result(grayImage <= t) = grayImage(grayImage <= t);
```

This is a much faster and cleaner way to access matrix elements conditionally.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
result = grayImage;
result(grayImage > t) = 0;
```

Comment: It worked just fine. Thanks for that, but why did you use "grayImage <= t" instead of "grayImage > t". I need to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: I added the alternative way to do this, with `grayImage > t`. Note that this condition is for the pixels where we want to place zeros. So we can either initialize `result` to the image, and then use this condition to set the relevant pixels to zero (the second option), or we can initialize `result` to zeros and use the complementary condition `grayImage <= t` to set the pixels where the image values are taken (the first option). Both options are equally valid.